# MVVM check Foreign Keys for changes

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

i got a mvvm app with EF6. I display my data in a datagrid using an ICollectionView.

When double clicking a row the row gets selected as "selecteduser as User" (for example). I have some FK which get displayed perfectly - selecteduser.Jobs.Jobname. I also got an edit window for the selected row. I'm parsing the whole View into the new window.

In this window i can select the job in combobox which gets it data from a JobsView which is created in the userviewmodel. It works just fine but **the FK data doesnt get updated until i recreate the view and refresh it.** Is there anything i could do to reload FK's? I'm using Inotifythingy for everything else.

Comment: Inotifythingy ??